# How to use increment and decrement operators for 'this' keyword?

Tags: c#, class, operator-keyword

I've been making a class in C#, but then I've faced an issue.

I implemented ++ and -- operators (also known as increment and decrement operators) to the class.

But then, in one function I had to use `this++;` and `this--;`.
However, this causes an error: 'The operand of the increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property, or indexer'.

Is there any way to use these operators for `this` keyword?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. What are you actually trying to achieve with `this++`? Without the context, it's really hard to understand what you expect it to do, and therefore how to help you. (It could only really make sense in the context of a mutable struct, and I'd really encourage you not to create your own mutable structs anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# complains when you are trying to apply these operators to `this` if the object is a class, because then `this` is a reference to the current object and you cannot assign it another value (and `x++` usually means `x = x + 1`).

`this++;` works, however, if the object is a struct, because you can copy the values of another struct to the current struct with `this = otherStruct;`

A workaround is to assign `this` to a temp:

```cs
var x = this;
x++;
```

The uneasy feeling, however, remains with this operation (See Jon Skeet's comment above). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

That's because you cannot "increment or decrement" classes or objects itselfs.

If you want to create another Person, you need to instance a new one:

```
Person person = new Person();
Person person2 = new Person();
```

and so on...

Increment and decrement are for integer for example.

Let say that in your class Person you have an attribute "Age", and in the birthday you want to put one more year, then you make:

```
Person myPerson = GetPerson();
myPerson .Age = 18;
myPerson .Age++
```

Here `Person.Age` will be 19.

And the `this` in this case will return the Person object

Comment: You can increment/decrement objects whose classes have the increment operator overloaded. All numeric types have it, and that's the real reason you can use it on them.

Comment: As an aside, this is why you store a bday as a DateTime, and not an age as an Integer ;)

Comment: I said I created the operators for my class, to increment/decrement property of my class and do necessary checks if the value is compatible.